# Unable to fetch Response For Google Distance matrix in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, google-distancematrix-api

I am using below code to get json response for Google maps api , Unable to get json response. Making get request using Alamofire pod.

```
Alamofire.request( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&key=<API_KEY>",method: .get,encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
         .responseString {response in
              print(response.request)  // original URL request
              print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
              print(response.data)     // server data
              print(response.result)
         }
```

Facing below error:

```
nil
nil
Optional(0 bytes)
FAILURE
```

Comment: yes , i dint mention in the post.

Comment: Have you try checking your request directly in browser?

Comment: yes works directly on browser with json output

Comment: Found the solution i had to pass headers  let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        ]

Comment: Its great that you solved it.

Comment: Thank you Nirav for quick suggestions

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: @Badrinath Can you Please share your working code i am facing issues with this

Comment: @Badrinath I am getting " The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." this error

Comment: Here is my Alamofire Request               Alamofire.request( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=\(start)&destinations=\(end)&key=AIzaSyDvt_KiUCtdb1kPEw4E4Dt68EuiF8PosAg", method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers)
                .responseString { response in

                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                    let json1 = json["rows"]
                    let json2 = json1[0]
                    let json3 = json2["elements"]
                    let dic = json3[0]