# Unable to get response from Google distance matrix api

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, swift4, google-distancematrix-api

I am using google distance matrix API and i am using following code

```
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [ "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" ]

        let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=\(start)&destinations=\(end)&key=AIzaSyDvt_KiUCtdb1kPEw4E4Dt68EuiF8PosAg"

        let header: HTTPHeaders = [ "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" ]

         Alamofire.request( url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : header) .responseString {  response in

            print(response.request)  // original URL request
            print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
            print(response.data)     // server data
            print(response.result)


        }
```

as per this [Unable to fetch Response For Google Distance matrix in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995419/unable-to-fetch-response-for-google-distance-matrix-in-swift) i am passing header but still i am getting following error. [image]

**Here is my URL with start and end**
 "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=Nanpura, Surat, Gujarat 395008, India&destinations=Adajan, Surat, Gujarat, India&key=AIzaSyDvt_KiUCtdb1kPEw4E4Dt68EuiF8PosAg "

Comment: Check your start & end variable. if it is not nil

Comment: can you please give me the value of your start and end?

Comment: @MayankJain please check my update code

Comment: I checked and it is working fine

Comment: @KhushbuDesai your url contains space so you need to do encoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should encode url, try with this

```
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?&origins=Nanpura, Surat, Gujarat 395008, India&destinations=Adajan, Surat, Gujarat, India&key=AIzaSyDvt_KiUCtdb1kPEw4E4Dt68EuiF8PosAg"
    let encodedUrl = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

    let header: HTTPHeaders = [ "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" ]

    Alamofire.request(encodedUrl! , method: .get,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
        .responseJSON { (data) in
            print(data)
    }
```

this will also work,

```
Alamofire.request(encodedUrl!, method: .get,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
            .responseString {response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)
        }
```

Response will be like this,

```
SUCCESS: {
    "destination_addresses" =     (
        "Adajan, Surat, Gujarat, India"
    );
    "origin_addresses" =     (
        "Nanpura, Surat, Gujarat 395008, India"
    );
    rows =     (
                {
            elements =             (
                                {
                    distance =                     {
                        text = "2.4 km";
                        value = 2433;
                    };
                    duration =                     {
                        text = "6 mins";
                        value = 373;
                    };
                    status = OK;
                }
            );
        }
    );
    status = OK;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked the request and it is working fine. I guess you are missing privacy setting in info.plist

[image]

[image]

Comment: No i have already added privacy settings in info.plist, my start name and end name containing some spaces so its correct or not?